# Hide columns in HTML table via CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<table class="list qy">
 <tr>
  <td>cell1</td>
  <td class="q">cell2</td>
  <td>cell3</td>
  <td class="y">cell4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table.qy td.q, table.qy td.y { display: none; }
```

**JS:**

```
function toggleQY(b) {
 $("table.list").toggleClass("qy")
}
```

It work quickly than running with JS for all TD ($("table.list td.q,table.list td.y")...)
But it don`t working in IE (8,9)...

As I understand class added for table, but table not refreshing...

I don`t have ideas (((

P.S. sorry for my English

Comment: Should work, but anyway try `visibility: hidden` - unless you need it to disappear from the document flow

Comment: I'm surprised if this actually works. Using `display: none` takes the table cell out of the document flow but then this creates a malformed table because you are missing a cell! You would either have to expand the other cells to fill that space with `colspan=2`... perhaps it would be best to wrap the cell in another div or just use `visibility: hidden`. Is this tabular data BTW?

Answer (score 2):

If all you're trying to do is toggle the visibility of the element, you could always just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$('table.list').find('.q, .y').toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hide the columns by default, then clicking the table to show them again?  then you probably want something like this...

The CSS to hide specific columns by default:

```
.list .q,  .list .y {
  display:none;
}
```

Then behind that, I am assuming want to toggle your hidden columns on table click.  The jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('table.list').on("click",function(){
    $(this).find('.q, .y').toggle();
  });  
})
```